# Communication between two or more instances of an ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I know that with AWS ECS's service-discovery you can make one service talk to the other by using the service.cluster pattern at the url (and service discovery does the rest for you). But I want to know if there is a way of doing one instance of a service talk to other container in the same service on AWS Elastic Container Service.

I have searched for this for a while now and decided to ask here as I wasn't able to find any conclusive ideas on how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate your ECS Service with an Application Load Balancer (ALB) which makes sure ECS will registers the tasks (i.e. one or more containers) with the ALB providing a uniform URL for the services to communicate with each other. ALB support path based routing to multiple Target Groups allowing micro-service style communication between tasks/services.

As per the AWS documentation[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html), you can use a single ALB for multiple services as ALB provides path-based routing and priority-rules. For further information you can also view this link [2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/microservice-delivery-with-amazon-ecs-and-application-load-balancers/) which explains how path-based routing can be used to forward request to different target groups with different ECS tasks/services.

Comment: With this i could make my tasks communicate with tasks on other services, but would i be able to communicate with the other tasks on my own service? i already use ALB for path based routing to communicate between the internet and other services (between services on the same cluster i use ECS's own service-discovery)